# What are the integer solutions to $z^2-y^2z+x^3=0$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

The question is to describe ALL integer solutions to the equation in the title. Of course, polynomial parametrization of all solutions would be ideal, but answers in many other formats are possible. For example, answer to famous Markoff equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=3xyz$ is given by Markoff tree. See also this previous question [Solve in integers: $y(x^2+1)=z^2+1$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414877) for some other examples of formats of acceptable answers. In general, just give as nice description of the integer solution set as you can.

If we consider the equation as quadratic in $z$ and its solutions are $z_1,z_2$, then $z_1+z_2=y^2$ while $z_1z_2=x^3$, so the question is equivalent to describing all pairs of integers such that their sum is a perfect square while their product is a perfect cube.

An additional motivation is that, together with a similar equation $xz^2-y^2z+x^2=0$, this equation is the smallest $3$-monomial equation for which I do not know how to describe all integer solutions. Here, the "smallest" is in the sense of question [What is the smallest unsolved Diophantine equation?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316708), see also [Can you solve the listed smallest open Diophantine equations?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400714) .

Comment: one solution is $y=8$ and $x=4$ so that the equation becomes $(z-8)^2=0$ or $z^2-16z+64=0$. I suspect this is the smallest possible solution.

Comment: @user, I think you meant $y=4$.

Comment: $x=y=z=0$ is a "smaller" solution.

Comment: Writing the equation as $(z-y^2/2)^2=(-x)^3+y^4/4$ provides a link with a family of elliptic curves parametrized by $y^2/2$

Comment: @GerryMyerson, if we invert the values of of $y$ and $x$, we get a delta negative. Maybe you can clarify what the value of $x$ should be.

Comment: @user, we're talking about $z^2-y^2z+x^3=0$, right? When $y=8$ and $x=4$, this becomes $z^2-64z+64=0$, not $z^2-16z+64=0$, which is what you wrote. But if you take $y=4$, then you do get $z^2-16z+64=0$. OK?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, you are right. I made the mistake of identifying $(z-8)^2$ with $(z-y)^2$ which is not the case. $z=8$ is the solution of the quadratic equation so the value of $y$ and $x$ must be identified after $(z-8)^2$ is expanded to read $(z-8)^2=z^2 -4^2*z +4^3$ which effectively gives the value $y=4$ and also $x=4$.

Comment: As briefly pointed out in my partial answer below, we can show the existence of solutions for any $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ by only assuming $z:=y^2$ so that $x=0$ and $y=y$. This includes also the trivial solution $x=y=z=0$. Of course, there are many other solutions for $x \neq 0$ (e.g., ($x=2, y= \pm 3, z=1$), ($x=2, y= \pm 3, z=8$), ($x=4, y= \pm 4, z=8$), and so forth).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We get $z(y^2-z)=x^3$. Thus $z=ab^2c^3$, $y^2-z=ba^2d^3$ for certain integers $a, b, c, d$ (that is easy to see considering the prime factorization). So $ab(bc^3+ad^3)=y^2$. Denote $a=TA$, $b=TB$ (each pair $(a, b) $ corresponds to at least one triple $(A, B, T)$, but possibly to several triples). You get $T^3AB(Bc^3+Ad^3)=y^2$.Thus $T$ divides $y$, say $y=TY$. We get $Y^2=TAB(Bc^3+Ad^3)$.

So, all solutions are obtained as follows: start with arbitrary $A, B, c, d$ and choose any $Y$ which square is divisible by $AB(Bc^3+Ad^3)$, the ratio is denoted by $T$ (if both $Y$ and $AB(Bc^3+Ad^3)$ are equal to 0, take arbitrary $T$).

Comment: Thank you. In my opinion, this is a good description of all integer solutions, so I will accept this answer.

Comment: Can this method also solve $xz^2-y^2z+x^2=0$, the second equation mentioned in the question?

Comment: Ah, yes, now I see that it works for this equation as well, thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Since the equation is NOT homogeneous, it is trivial to find
infinite families of solutions with $g=\gcd(x,y)>1$. For instance,
choose any integers $a$ and $b$, set $c=ab^2-a^2$, so multiplying
by $c^8$ gives $(ac^4)^2-ac^4(bc^2)^2+c^9=0$, giving the trivial
solutions $(x,y,z)=(c^3,bc^2,ac^4)$, but there are many other ways to
find ``trivial'' solutions.

If you assume $g=\gcd(x,y)=1$, the solution is pretty standard:
since we have a monic second degree equation in $z$, there exist
integer solutions if and only if the discriminant is a square, giving
the auxiliary equation $y^4-4x^3=d^2$, rewritten as $((y^2-d)/2)((y^2+d)/2)=x^3$,
and since the factors are coprime, they are both cubes, say $a^3$ and $b^3$,
so $x=ab$, $y^2=a^3+b^3$, hence $z=b^3$. The equation in $y$ is a standard
superFermat equation of elliptic type, which is entirely parametrized by the
following three parametrizations (see for instance my GTM 240 chapter 14 for
a proof), where $s$ and $t$ are coprime integers, and any solution belongs
to one and only one parametrization:
$$(a,b,y)=(s(s+2t)(s^2-2ts+4t^2),-4t(s-t)(s^2+ts+t^2),\pm(s^2-2ts-2t^2))$$
with $s$ odd and $s\not\equiv t\pmod3$,
$$(a,b,y)=(s^4-4ts^3-6t^2s^2-4t^3s+t^4,2(s^4+2ts^3+2t^3s+t^4),3(s^2-t^2)(s^4+2s^3t+\
6s^2t^2+2st^3+t^4))$$
with $s\not\equiv t\pmod{2}$ and $s\not\equiv t\pmod 3$,
$$(a,b,y)=(-3s^4+6t^2s^2+t^4,3s^4+6t^2s^2-t^4,6st(3s^4+t^4))$$
with $s\not\equiv t\pmod{2}$ and $3\nmid t$.

Comment: Thank you! The question is to describe ALL solutions, including all "trivial" ones, but I am happy to also have a parametrized description of coprime solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an infinite family of solutions resulting from setting
$x=A z$ for integer $A$.

For example set $x=2z$ and get

$$g(y,z)=-(y^2 - 8*z^2 - z)*z$$

The quadratic factor is conic and
[Wolfram Alpha gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+-y%5E2*z+%2B+8*z%5E3+%2B+z%5E2+++over+integers) infinitely many integer
solutions in terms of powers of square root of two,
e.g: $f(2*36,102,36)=0$

Potential attack might be to try rational $A$ and then find integral
points on a conic with rational coefficients.

---

There exists parametrization of the rational solutions
since your equation is a rational surface:

$X1=-1/2*s^2*t/(2*t^3 - s),Y1=-1/2*s^2/(2*t^3 - s),Z1=1/2*s^3*t^3/(4*t^6 - 4*s*t^3 + s^2)$

Comment: Why is this disliked?

Answer (score 1):

We already have a description of all solutions by @FedorPetrov, and *co-prime solutions* by @HenriCohen, and some promises for some special solutions.

Let me present a very simple and explicite family of special solutions parametrized by natural variables $\ t\ $ and $\ n.$

Let

$$ z_k\ :=\ (t^2-1)^{6\cdot n-k} $$
for $\ k=1\ $ or $\ 2.\ $ Then:

$$ z_1+z_2\ =\ \left((t^2-1)^{3\cdot n-1}\cdot t\right)^2 $$
and
$$ z_1\cdot z_2\ =\ \left(t^2-1)^{4\cdot n-1}\right)^3 $$

is an explicite (*while very special*) family.

---

**PS:**

$$ 2^3+1\ =\ 3^2 $$
$$ 2^3\cdot 1\ =\ 2^3 $$

**PPS:**

If $\,\ z_1\ $ and $\ z_2\,\ $ form a solution then so do
$\,\ w_1:= a^6\cdot z_1\ $ and
$\ w_2\ := a^6\cdot z_2.$

Thus, above, we could have:

$$ w_1\ :=\ a^6\cdot(t^2-1)^5 $$
$$ w_2\ :=\ a^6\cdot(t^2-1)^4 $$

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial (trivial) answer.
Let $z := y^2$. Then, $x$ must be equal to zero, while $y$, by construction, is free to run over the integers.